# Sum the Column A Only if Column B contains?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have the table in google-sheets which looks:

[image]

I need to sum sums according to the Card = "HDFC"

**i.e need to display in cell 1408.8**

I tried:

```
=COUNTIF(C3:C1000,"HDFC")
```

but its give count only not sure how to use to get sumif on column B if matches column C

Comment: sumproduct() or sumif(). If you got the criteria correct with countif() then sumif() will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `SUMIFS()` must work. Try-

```
=SUMIFS(B4:B,C4:C,E4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

or these:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B:B; C:C="HDFC"))
```

---

```
=INDEX(QUERY(B:C; "select sum(B) where C = 'HDFC'"); 2)
```